# How to mount Nexus 4 to 14.04

Tags: mount

How do i mount my nexus 4 to my laptop running 14.04. 
I need a method that mount and unmounts the nexus 4 like how windows does it. 
I don't want complicated methods. 
Thanks!!

Comment: You do mean how to transfer files and such, not how to install ubuntu on the phone or something along those lines?

Comment: MTP is enabled but the phone still doesn't show any files. 54N1: the Nexus 4 doesn't support USB storage. I really wish they would bring USB storage back in a future release, other methods are a nightmare to configure.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go "Settings" -> "Storage" -> Upper right corner button -> "USB computer connection" -> Check "Media device (MTP)".
2. Connect phone to computer by USB cable.

Works?

Answer (score 1):

On the phone once it is connected to the pc press, "turn on USB storage".. then on the computer it will be mounted which you can view by the filebrowser. Or it might appear on your Desktop as a mounted drive.